# C#: What's the best way to ensure that two functions (2 different classes) never get called independently of each other?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

For example I have classes `Branch` and `Node`. My code expects a bi-directional connection between them, so I must call:

```
branch.addNode(node);
node.addBranch(branch);
```

to connect them. I don't want `branch.addNode()` to be ever called without the corresponding `node.addBranch()`. What's the best way to achieve that?

I can probably make `Node.addBranch()` protected and make `Branch` inherit `Node` and just call from `Branch` class:

```
// Branch class
public void addNode(Node node)
{
    this.myNodeList.add(node);
    node.addBranch(this);
}
```

but to me it looks like a hack. Is there a better way?

Comment: probably none of those classes should have an `Add`-method at all. Instead create some intermediate class that adds both.

Comment: I thought about this, but where and how would you store the connections? Would you still store them inside Node/Branch objects or in some dictionary inside the intermediate class?

Comment: The "best" way is to redesign it so that the consumer isn't responsible for doing this. Use `internal` methods to enable them to work together while preventing the consumer from doing incomplete actions.

Comment: There's no consumer, it's one assembly. It's just for me, to make sure I'm using the best programming approach possible internal won't help me in this situation.

Comment: Step 1: Refactor this portion of code so that it's isolated. You are the consumer. Put yourself in those roles separately.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously consider *not* making the connection bidirectional. I don't know what the particular scenario is, but in my experience you can usually recast your problem so that it's based on a directed graph instead.

If you then, still, occasionally need to walk the graph in the opposite direction, you can [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_graph) it. All directed graphs can be transposed by reversing the arrows. Depending on the size of the graph this *could* be an expensive operation, but again depending on the actual usage scenario, there are often solutions to those problems as well. For instance, if you can make the graph immutable, you can use memoisation to deal with performance problems.

Bidirectional connections in code tends to cause all sorts of trouble, so it's well worth the effort to look for alternatives. I can't recall when was the last time I designed a system with bidirectional connections, but I guess that it's more than a decade ago.